# Customizing many UIButtons in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, uibutton, calculator, iboutlet

In an iPhone app I have a bunch of UIButtons (like around 60 buttons) in one view. I am using the following method to customize the look of the buttons.

```
- (void) setButtonAttributes:(UIButton *) buttonName withTitle:(NSString *)title withImage:(NSString *) imageSuffix
{
    NSString *unpressedName, *pressedName;
    pressedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pressed%@.png", imageSuffix];
    unpressedName = [@"un" stringByAppendingString: pressedName];
    buttonName.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    buttonName.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [buttonName setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ([imageSuffix isEqualToString:@""] || [imageSuffix isEqualToString:@"brown"] ||  [imageSuffix isEqualToString:@"green"])
    {
    buttonName.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    [buttonName setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonName setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [buttonName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:unpressedName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pressedName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    else
    {
    [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:unpressedName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pressedName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [buttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(playClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

}

Therefore, I am calling this method around 60 times in the  - (void)viewDidLoad of my view. For example:

```
 [self setButtonAttributes:firstButton withTitle:@"First" withImage:@"brown"];
```

Some of the buttons are visible in the IB. But also there are buttons that are not visible in IB so I am using the following to present them:

```
secondButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(64, 394, BUTTOM_WIDTH, BUTTOM_HEIGHT);
secondButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, BUTTOM_WIDTH, BUTTOM_HEIGHT);
[self setButtonAttributes:secondButton withTitle:@"Second" withImage:@"brown"];    
[secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someSelector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[somePane addSubview:secondButton];  //somePane is a scrollview.
```

And all these 60 buttons have an IBOutlet defined in the header file of the view. For example:

```
 IBOutlet  UIButton *firstButton;
```

When I compare my app with let say the calculator app of iPhone, I notice that in the iPhone's calculator the buttons feel much snappier than my app. So basically, my problem is that the response time of the buttons in my app are much slower compared with iPhone's calculator. I was wondering if it has anything to do with the way I customized the buttons as I explained in the code above? And if that's the case, what is the correct way of customizing these many buttons?

Comment: have you measured the performance without setting the individual characteristics?

Comment: Well, I believe I noticed the performance issue after I set up images and other settings (as in the code above). That's why I can only think it's because of this. Besides, there is not much I can change as far as what goes behind the scenes when any of those buttons are pressed. So I thought I am not setting these settings correctly and efficiently.